# Hint on using a regex lookaround needed

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

Suppose there is a sequence ...a...b...a...b...c... ,where a,b and c are string constants. And dots represent arbitrary number of some other (not a, b or c) symbols between a,b and c.

I would like to match "a...b...c" a laziest way (the last a-b-c triad), but the regexp engine grabs the bigger "a...b...a...b...c" and goes further.

I tried to use a negative lookahead in forms of `a\w+b\w+(?!a)\w+c` or `a\w+b\w+?(?!a)\w+?c`  etc. but didn't succeed so far.

Comment: Are `a`, `b` and `c` multicharacter strings?

Comment: Yes, they are multichar constant strings.

Comment: `a(?:(?!a|b|c).)*b(?:(?!a|b|c).)*c` is the only way. https://regex101.com/r/uCDgY4/1

Comment: @sln: There are at least 2 ways. The last branch  in each TGT is not necessary if you use a lazy quantifier. I noticed that this *usually* speeds up matching somewhat.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You didn't read the question. `(not a, b or c) symbols between a,b and c`. There is only 1 way to do it. And I have no idea what _TGT_ is or what you are talking about in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [*tempered greedy tokens*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) here in between the three parts.

Imagine `a` is `abc`, `b` is `bff` and `c` is `cca`. Then, you'd use

```
(?s)abc(?:(?!abc).)*?bff(?:(?!abc).)*?cca
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmBf7Y/2)

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - same as `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` modifier, makes `.` match newlines
- `abc` - a literal string `abc` or some pattern #1
- `(?:(?!abc).)*?` - any 0+ chars other than newline that does not start an `abc` sequence, as few as possible
- `bff` - a literal string `bff` or some pattern #2
- `(?:(?!abc).)*?` - see above
- `cca` - a literal string `cca` or some pattern #3

Comment: Wiktor, thank you fir your solution - it works fine! Yes, I need to catch multiple matches (actually your example multimatches well already). 

And also I have linefeeds as my "dots", so I modified your work a bit to `abc(?:(?!abc)[\S\s])*?bff(?:(?!abc|bff)[\S\s])*?cca` so it surives with linefeeds between the string constants.

Comment: To make `.` match line breaks, you need to to pass a DOTALL modifier - `(?s)abc(?:(?!abc).)*?bff(?:(?!abc|bff).)*?cca`

Comment: BTW I think a "|bff" alternative is excessive (can be removed).

Comment: Uhm...seems that even this `abc(?:(?!abc)[\S\s])*?bff[\S\s]*?cca` works!

Comment: @einy It depends on the input string. See https://regex101.com/r/hbmaqI/1. I'd prefer to keep `(?:(?!abc).)*` tempered greedy token before `cca`.

Comment: -1 the OP @einy stated requirement => _`a...b...c` And dots represent arbitrary number of some other (not a, b or c) symbols between a, b and c._  Your regex don't work buddy.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use looakarounds for this. Put `.*` at the beginning of the regexp, and put what you want to match into a capture group:

```
.*(a.*b.*c)
```

Then use `.group(1)` to get the contents of the capture group.

The greedy `.*` at the beginning makes this find the last triad.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/c2sWiS/1)

Comment: No, OP does not need the last occurrence, but all of them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The question says "the last a-b-c triad"

Comment: I understand it is at the end here, in this string, but not in the general case. There would be no need using lookaheads otherwise.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What is the "general case"? The question only describes one case. I don't think lookaheads are required.